# Add a dictionary to an array in Swift

Tags: arrays, dictionary, swift

I created an array of dictionary, but I have an error, when I tried to add my object (a dictionary) to my array.
I have this error "AnyObject does not have a member named 'append'"

```
var posts=[Dictionary<String,AnyObject>]()

var post=Dictionary<String,AnyObject>()
var attachment=Dictionary<String,AnyObject>()

...

post=["id":"a", "label":"b"]
attachment=["id":"c", "image":"d"]
var newPost = [post, attachment]

posts.append(newPost) <- AnyObject does not have a member named 'append'
```

I don't understand. Maybe I haven't initialize the array correctly ?

**UPDATE** / **SOLVED**

```
var posts=[Dictionary<String,Dictionary<String,AnyObject>>]()

var post=Dictionary<String,AnyObject>()
var attachment=Dictionary<String,AnyObject>()

...

post=["id":"a", "label":"b"]
attachment=["id":"c", "image":"d"]
var newPost = ["post":post, "attachment":attachment]

posts.append(newPost) <- AnyObject does not have a member named 'append'
```

EDIT : newPost is a instance of dictionary and posts an array of dictionaries

Comment: This is working for me in a swift playground without protest and looks good. Are you using the latest xcode?

Comment: The 2nd version of the code works just fine. Please provide more details if it's not working for you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`append` is to add an item, whereas you are trying to append another array (`post` is an array of dictionaries). You can use the `+=` operator:

```
posts += newPost
```

or use the `extend` method (which is equivalent to the `+=` operator):

```
posts.extend(newPost)
```

or add elements individually:

```
posts.append(post)
posts.append(attachment)
```

Comment: When I use posts += newPost I have an error "[(Dictionary<String, AnyObject>)] is not identical to UInt8". I found a solution with NSMutableArray and addObject, but I don't like it, because my challenge is to code everything in Swift.

Comment: What about using `extend`? What's the type of `newPost`? Is it an array or a single instance of `Dictionary`?

Comment: newPost is a single instance of dictionary and posts an array of dictionaries (see my edit). When I do arrayOfposts.extend(postToAdd) I have this error : Dictionary<String, Dictionary<String, AnyObject>> is not identical to (String, Dictionary<String, AnyObject>) I've done a mistake with the types but where ?

Comment: The code you replaced works just fine. However you should avoid replacing code in your question, because: that invalidates answers, including mine. I'm going to revert your question to the previous version, please post your code and additional comment in a section below the original question, prefixing with an *update* label

Comment: Ok reverted to original question and added the modified code in a separate section - check it out to verify that I didn't missed anything

Comment: Thank you @Antonio, I'll pay more attention next time !

Answer (score 0):

If you want each post to be an array of post and argument:

```
var posts=[[Dictionary<String,AnyObject>]]()
```

Also, you can define the type for post and attachment without creating empty objects:

```
var post:Dictionary<String,AnyObject>
var attachment:Dictionary<String,AnyObject>
```