# Swift: How to add dictionary arrays to an array?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, dictionary

Can I add dictionary arrays (is this the correct term for a dictionary key holding multiple values?) to an array?

```
var dictionary = [String: [String]]()
var array = [String]()

var data1:String = "55a"
var data2:String = "95a"
var data3:String = "66"
var data4:String = "25"
var data5:String = "88b"
var data6:String = "#"

dictionary["3"] = [data1, data2, data3, data4, data5, data6]

var data7:String = "#"
var data8:String = "#"
var data9:String = "#"
var data10:String = "#"
var data11:String = "#"
var data12:String = "#"

dictionary["2"] = [data7, data8, data9, data10, data11, data12]

var data13:String = "100"
var data14:String = "101"
var data15:String = "102"
var data16:String = "103"
var data17:String = "104"
var data18:String = "105"

dictionary["1"] = [data13, data14, data15, data16, data17, data18]
```

I tried this:

```
array.extend([dictionary["1"], dictionary["2"], dictionary["3"]])
```

but there was an error "Cannot invoke 'extend' with an argument list of type '([[(String)?])"..

How do I add dictionary["1"], ["2"] & ["3"] accordingly into the array?

Comment: you have to check this out 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26897176/add-a-dictionary-to-an-array-in-swift

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case you are not interested in the order you might try:

```
array.extend(flatMap(dictionary.values, {$0}))
```

If order is important you might build your *optionalArrays* first:

```
let optionalArrays = [dictionary["1"], dictionary["2"], dictionary["3"]]
array.extend(flatMap(optionalArrays, {$0 ?? []}))
```

i.e. your dictionary returns an optional array, this causes the error you reported.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks! It helps! But could you explain briefly what does "flatMap" & the use of "$0", "??" and "[ ]" mean?

Comment: `flatMap` is similar to `map`, difference is that the function you pass has to return an array. Then all the mapped arrays will be _flattened_ into a single array. In the first example I just use `{$0}` as the mapping function, it just returns the dictionary value which is an array. Thus all your arrays will be _flattened_ into one by `flatMap`. Second example is similar, I just have to take care of the possibility that the dictionary value may be `Nothing`. `{ $0 ?? []}` just returns the dictionary value if it exists or the empty array `[]` in case the dictionary key has no value.

Comment: Then should we also consider the possibility of having no dictionary values in the first example, and use { $0 ?? [ ] }?

Comment: `dictionary.values` iterate the actual values. You get an `Optional` type when you ask the dictionary for a value corresponding to a key, since for that key there might be no value. Asking for all the values can at least lead to an empty list. In which case you will end up with an empty array.

Answer (score 5):

Your array type declaration is not correct. Please try below one

```
var array: [[String:[String]] = []
```

Comment: But what if I want a [String] array? As in all the values for the keys in the dictionary broken down and added to the array? (Total 24 objects in the new array)

Comment: For String array use - var array: [String] = []

Answer (score 3):

If you wanted an array of arrays of `Strings`, you need to change your array's type to be `[[String]]`, as the other answers said.

But, when getting values out of your dictionary, you shouldn't force unwrap! It may work for this example, but in the future you'll likely get into trouble with:

> 'fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional
>   value'

You should check to see if a value exists in the dictionary for that key, using optional binding for example:

```
if let value = dictionary["1"] {
    array.append(value)
}

// ...
```

Or, you could get all the values from your dictionary into an array like so:

```
let array = Array(dictionary.values)
```

---

If you actually did want an array of `String`s, you could use `flatMap`:

```
let array = flatMap(dictionary.values) { $0 }
```

Comment: Thank you! I want to ask though: 1) If "$0.1" means the value, then does "$0" means the keys in the dictionary? 2) By using "dictionary.values", does it mean that the values are changed to key, and then "$0" now refers to those keys (which are values originally)?

Comment: Also.. 3) Does flatMap(dictionary) {$0.1} performs the same as flatMap(dictionary.values) {$0}? Thank you so much..

Comment: In response to 1 and 2, I've changed it to `Array(dictionary.values)` instead of using `map`. But no, `$0.0` would refer to the key. `$0` refers to the (key, value) tuple, the `.0` or `.1` refer to the key and value respectively. In response to 3, yes, `flatMap(dictionary) {$0.1}` has the same effect as `flatMap(dictionary.values) { $0 }`.

Comment: Thanks again. But can I ask why use `Array(dictionary.values)` instead of the previous `map(dictionary.values) {$0}` ?

Answer (score 2):

Your `array` variable must be an `Array` of `Array` with `String` elements.
Also don't forget to unwrap the values of the dictionaries by adding `!`.

Try this:

```
var dictionary = [String: [String]]()
var array = [[String]]()


var data1:String = "55a"
var data2:String = "95a"
var data3:String = "66"
var data4:String = "25"
var data5:String = "88b"
var data6:String = "#"

dictionary["3"] = [data1, data2, data3, data4, data5, data6]

var data7:String = "#"
var data8:String = "#"
var data9:String = "#"
var data10:String = "#"
var data11:String = "#"
var data12:String = "#"

dictionary["2"] = [data7, data8, data9, data10, data11, data12]

var data13:String = "100"
var data14:String = "101"
var data15:String = "102"
var data16:String = "103"
var data17:String = "104"
var data18:String = "105"

dictionary["1"] = [data13, data14, data15, data16, data17, data18]
array.extend([dictionary["1"]!, dictionary["2"]!, dictionary["3"]!])
```

Comment: Thanks! But how do I do it if I want a [String] array instead of a [[String]] array?

Comment: You'll probably need to iterate through the elements of the internal array (dictionary["1"], dictionary["2" and so on]) and add them to the external array (array), because you have an array of arrays.

Answer (score 1):

Dictionary values are returned as `optionals` (thus indicating if a value exists for a key) so use the `'!'` to unwrap the values of each dictionary array (i.e. `[dictionary["1"]!`)

And as suggested in other answers change your array type as it currently defined as arrays of string rather then an array of dictionaries.

Comment: Thank you! But I was actually thinking of having a [String] array where each value for every key in the dictionary is broken down and added into this new array. Having a total of 24 objects in this new [String] array. Is that possible?